# Which is the directory in the Raspbian Jessie OS where the Iceweasel (Firefox port) files are kept in?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, directory-listing, iceweasel

**Which is the directory in the Raspbian Jessie OS where the Iceweasel (Firefox port) files are kept in?**
I am trying to install Java 8u101 into my Raspberry Pi's Iceweasel but I'm always unsuccessful...

Comment: It's not really a good idea to try to install Sun's ... er, I mean, Oracle's tarball; you should probably just stick to the OpenJDK packages...

Answer (score 0):

In Debian, it's in `/usr/lib/mozilla/`

So you can install the plugin by

`ln -sv /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_101/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins`

(or wherever your java plugin is)